# Android - Where is the best place to place the "addProvider" / "Security.insertProviderAt" code line

Tags: android, bouncycastle, spongycastle

I would like, in an Android application where is the best place to place the following piece of code:

```
static {
    Security.insertProviderAt(new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);
//  Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
}
```

Some guys do it in a subclass of `Application`, but I really don't want to subclass `Application`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I also don't like the idea of inserting it subclass of `Application`. I prefer to add this static initialising block in my main `Security/CryptoManager` class for security related things, whose instance you know what you will always refered to/create before doing any operation which will require SC.

Just to be on safer side, you can make sure that this static block is executed by calling some method like

```
CyrptoManager.init()
```